# Given the following circumstances, how can I jailbreak my iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, windows, jailbreak, virtualbox

So, I want to jailbreak my iPhone, I know my options but lack the resources or knowledge.

Here's what I've got: Windows 10 64 bit PC, iPhone 6+ 128gb on iOS 12.4.6, MACOS High Sierra vbox machine.

First option: Use Checkra1n jailbreak on my vbox machine and directly solve the issue.

First Problem: I cannot connect my iPhone directly to the VM as it detects the device as a USB 3.0 and not an actual phone. I have the vbox extension pack installed, 'USB 3.0' USB controller and the iPhone filter applied but checkra1n will never detect the phone in order to apply the jailbreak.

Second option: Downgrade the iPhone to the jailbreakable, unsigned iOS 12.4 version using itunes and ipsw's and use the unc0ver app on the phone.

Second problem: 12.4 is unsigned. Can't downgrade as far as I know.

Third option: You tell me. Please.

What I'm asking is to let me know how to solve the problems listed above or supply a working alternative method to the circumstance

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to jailbreak (as far as I know) using a virtual machine

Instead here is what i recommend you do [(source)](https://github.com/foxlet/bootra1n):

> Download [bootra1n 0.10.1](https://github.com/foxlet/bootra1n)
>
> Download [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), press SELECT, open the ISO file, and press START to flash it to your USB drive.
>
> Reboot your computer and enter your BIOS's boot menu.
>
> - Select the flash drive, and it should boot into the login prompt
> - Log in as `anon`, with password `voidlinux`
> - At the `$` prompt, enter `sudo checkra1n`

Further information can be found [here](https://github.com/foxlet/bootra1n)